# install openerp 7 with db server on different machine

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am trying to install openerp 7 on ubuntu 12.04 inside a lxc container. The db server is on the host machine. Everything worked fine but when I try to access the webclient for the first time I get an error in browser (in terminal also) that openerp can't connect to db server. 
Here is my openerp-server.conf file:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
debug_mode = True
db_host = '10.0.3.1'
db_port = 5432
db_user = openerp
db_password = openerp
db_name = openerp
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
```

I have also tried with

```
db_host = 10.0.3.1
```

When I start the server I got this info messages :

```
2013-01-08 22:46:39,688 654 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20130106-001538
2013-01-08 22:46:39,688 654 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons
2013-01-08 22:46:39,688 654 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2013-01-08 22:46:39,688 654 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2013-01-08 22:46:39,688 654 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
2013-01-08 22:46:40,106 654 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2013-01-08 22:46:40,106 654 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
```

The log file has 777 permissions and is empty.
This is part of the error when I try to access openerp from browser:

```
ERROR postgres openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 433, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

2013-01-08 22:48:21,553 654 ERROR postgres openerp.netsvc: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 289, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
```

The db server is accepting connections from the lxc container, I have created a small python script to test this and it worked.

Thank you

Comment: Probable cause is that the server is not using that config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third line of your output says that OpenERP is looking for the database server on `localhost`.  I'm guessing that OE is not seeing your config file.  As a quick test you can run OE manually with something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/openerp-server --conf /path/to/config_file
```

and see if that works.  If it does, locate the appropriate startup script and adjust it with your config file and log file parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I had recently install OpenERP v7.0, This blog helps me a lot. 
Refer **[Install OpenERP 7.0 on Ubuntu](http://jayvora.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-on-ubuntu-1204.html).**

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by modifing this file:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/config.py
```

In there there is a section:

```
    if self.options['db_password']:
        if sys.platform == 'win32' and not self.options['db_host']:
            self.options['db_host'] = 'localhost'
        #if self.options['db_host']:
        #    self._generate_pgpassfile()

    if opt.save:
        self.save()
```

Before "if op.save:" add:

```
    self.options['db_host'] = '<address_of_db_host>'
```